Why do these semantically identical statements return different results?
This is SQL server:
select cast(10e10 * 3539628 + 3539628 as bigint)
select cast(353962800000000000 + 3539628 as bigint)


First result: 353962800003539648
Second result: 353962800003539628

The numbers are not the same (second digit from right). Can anyone please explain why?
I tried to generate a unique bigint number and got different results depending on the order of CAST.

Because they aren't semantically identical. You have different data types in your queries.

If you skip the cast the difference will become more obvious. https://dbfiddle.uk/nfifunLM

Your statement that that are semantically identical is false; they are not the same. In the first query you start off with a float value (10e10), which you then multiple and then add a value to. This results in the float value 3.5396280000354E+17, which you then cast to a bigint giving the value 353962800003539648, the closest representation to full integer value the float can provide (as float is a base-2 value, and only accurate to 15 digits). If you did CAST(10e10 * 3539628 + 3539628 +2 AS bigint) you would, infact, get the same value (353962800003539648).
In the second statement you have a numeric(18,0), which you then add a number to. This results in the numeric(19,0) value 353962800003539628 which you then cast to a bigint. As it's a numeric(19,0) it's more than capable of displaying all 18 digits accurately.
As 353962800003539628 can't be stored in a float (it lacks the accuracy), then you don't get the same values.

Thank you for the time and effort you took to answer my question. I had an inkling that it could be something to do with float, but I had no idea that sql server assumes float when dealing with large numbers. I wonder why it wouldn’t automatically cast to numeric (36,18) or something given that float lacks accuracy.

"but I had no idea that sql server assumes float" it doesn't, which you can see from the above. The reason you had a float is because you had a float literal in the expression (10e10), and everything else was cast to a float as the data type has the highest data type precedence.
